# ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to configure a Git project in Jenkins using the Git plugin.

In the 'Manage Jenkins' page I enter repository URL in the Git configuration.

However when I'm building the project I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\Users\m.kothamasu\.jenkins\jobs\gvp web\workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$4.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:476)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:379)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:846)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:879)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1252)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)

Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Users\m.kothamasu\GIT init C:\Users\m.kothamasu\.jenkins\jobs\gvp web\workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1301)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1297)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1084)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$4.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:474)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\m.kothamasu\GIT" (in directory "C:\Users\m.kothamasu\.jenkins\jobs\gvp web\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:780)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:360)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1321)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: error=5 means:

file is not executable or not accessible

Comment: hi how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Check that you did specify the git *executable* in your Jenkins Git plugin configuration:

`C:\Users\m.kothamasu\GI` doesn't look like an exe.

That would be similar to [JENKINS-6181](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6181) (which was about perforce, but the idea remains the same).

Check also [JENKINS-12353](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12353), to make sure `<git/bin>` is in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

you can set Git location in Jenkins server/node configuration:

goto Configure, under section Node Properties mark checkbox Tools Location and set yours path to Git.